# Apply (xaml) style to DataTemplate control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I would like to apply a style, in this case of a 'ListViewItem', to a control within a DataTemplate.

**Style (sample) code:**

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">       
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**DataTemplate (sample) code:**

```
<ListView.View>
  <GridView>
    <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Text"/>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding MyImage}"/>
                    <Label Content="{Binding MyLabelText}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
  </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

What is the solution to apply the Background, BorderBrush and Foreground style to the `<Label>` within the DataTemplate?

Thank you in advance.

*Note:* I already read the question and answers of ['Applying style to elements inside a DataTemplate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691002/applying-style-to-elements-inside-a-datatemplate), but I would like to use xaml (so without C# code).

Comment: Are you trying to style the Label, or the ListViewItem?

Comment: I would like to apply the style of the ListViewItem to the Label. So when I click on/ select the Label (I assume it acts like a ListViewItem?), it uses the same Background, BorderBrush and Foreground (as the ListViewItem).

Comment: Styling the ListViewItem would change the background of the entire row upon selection. Is that the desired behavior, or do you only want the Label background changed?

Comment: It is desired that styling the ListViewItem changes the background of the entire row upon selection. (At this moment, the style of the Label doesn't change).

Answer (score 0):

The following XAML styles the ListViewItem (assuming Items is your collection):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
                    </Trigger.Setters>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Text"/>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding MyImage}" Width="20"/>
                            <Label Content="{Binding MyLabelText}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Looks right, but the trigger doesn't need to be a multitrigger.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't. I was assuming the question was about template location/declaration and used his existing template.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't working. The Foreground of the <Label> is Black instead of White. The items of the other columns is white (as desired).

Comment: Updated with custom templates for text.

Comment: The following code does seem to solve the issue:  <Label Content="{Binding MyLabelText}" Foreground="{Binding Foreground,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                            AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"/>. Thanks for the suggestion of 'RelativeSource'!